# How to install Microsoft Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server in Quiet mode

Tags: sql-server, command-line, utilities

Do you know how to install Microsoft Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server in Quiet mode (/quiet) and moreover how to accept the license terms to do so?

```
msiexec /i MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi /qn {IACCEPTLICENSETERMS ????}
```

In the same way as I accepted

> MSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS

for `msodbcsql.msi`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer to the question in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9fa14c22-5c78-4955-b50c-7a00c85d2ed0/how-to-install-microsoft-command-line-utilities-11-for-sql-server-in-quiet-mode?forum=sqlexpress&prof=required

To sum up :

```
msiexec /i "C:\Users\administrator.CONTOSO\Downloads\MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi" /qn IACCEPTMSSQLCMDLNUTILSLICENSETERMS=YES
```